# tf API: Axes/order of rotation

Tags: ros, transforms, coordinate-system, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello ROS users!

I'm working with **tf** and I've a few questions about the API.

I am defining frames such that Yaw is applied around Z, followed by Pitch around the new Y and then Roll around new X.

Consider a transform from `base_link --> camera_frame`. Assuming I only have constant rotation between the frames (zero translation), here's how I create the transform:

```
//Fixed transform values
double roll, pitch, yaw;
yaw = DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(90); // 90 degrees around Z 
pitch = DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(0); // 0 degrees around new Y
roll = DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(-90); // -90 degrees around new X

//Create Quaternion from Euler angles
tf::Quaternion quat;
quat.setRPY(roll, pitch, yaw);
//quat.setEuler(pitch, roll, -yaw); // 

//Set rotations
geometry_msgs::TransformStamped bLink_to_cam;

bLink_to_cam.transform.rotation.x = quat.x();
bLink_to_cam.transform.rotation.y = quat.y();
bLink_to_cam.transform.rotation.z = quat.z();
bLink_to_cam.transform.rotation.w = quat.w();

//Set translations
bLink_to_cam.transform.translation.x = 0;
bLink_to_cam.transform.translation.y = 0;
bLink_to_cam.transform.translation.z = 0;
```

In another node, I have a `tf::TransformListener` object which receives this transform. Here I print out the values :

```
void printEulerAngles(tf::StampedTransform& transform){
    double roll, pitch, yaw;
    tf::Matrix3x3 m(transform.getRotation());

    m.getRPY(roll, pitch, yaw);
    //m.getEulerZYX(yaw, pitch, roll);
    ROS_INFO("\nRoll    : %.3f\n"
            "Pitch  : %.3f\n"
            "Yaw    : %.3f\n",
            RADIANS_TO_DEGREES(roll), RADIANS_TO_DEGREES(pitch), RADIANS_TO_DEGREES(yaw)  );

}
```

I expected to see the transform as defined above. However, I see Roll, Pitch, Yaw  (90,90, 0). I did some research and found that `setRPY()` and `getRPY()` follow this convention:

- (roll around X, pitch around Y and yaw around z) around **fixed axes**.

Here are my questions:

1. How do I define rotations when I need to rotate (w.r.t to base_link axes) in the following convention?

- (yaw around **Z**, then pitch around **new Y**, then roll around **new X**)

2. Once I get the above rotation from tf, how do I modify the `printEulerAngles()` method to display them in the same convention as above?

I'd really appreciate any assistance in understanding **tf**. Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/247808/tf-api:-axes/order-of-rotation/) by [Venkat Ganesh](https://answers.ros.org/users/26837/venkat-ganesh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 57 on 2016-11-10

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think you are looking for the `setEulerYPR` and `getEulerYPR` functions of `tf::Matrix3x3`. As far as I can tell, these follow the convention you are describing.

To generate the quaternion:

```
//Fixed transform values
double roll, pitch, yaw;
yaw = DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(90); // 90 degrees around Z 
pitch = DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(0); // 0 degrees around new Y
roll = DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(-90); // -90 degrees around new X

//Create Matrix3x3 from Euler Angles
tf::Matrix3x3 m_rot;
m_rot.setEulerYPR(yaw, pitch, roll);

// Convert into quaternion
tf::Quaternion quat;
m_rot.getRotation(quat);
```

Your printEuler would then be

```
void printEulerAngles(tf::StampedTransform& transform){
    double roll, pitch, yaw;
    tf::Matrix3x3 m(transform.getRotation());
    int solution_number = 1;

    m.getEulerYPR(yaw, pitch, roll, solution_number);
    ROS_INFO("\nRoll    : %.3f\n"
            "Pitch  : %.3f\n"
            "Yaw    : %.3f\n",
            RADIANS_TO_DEGREES(roll), RADIANS_TO_DEGREES(pitch), RADIANS_TO_DEGREES(yaw)  );
}
```

However, like I wrote in your [previous question](http://answers.ros.org/question/247673/tf-fixed-transforms/), there can be multiple representations of an identical rotation, so your angles might not be the same. You can play around witht the `solution_number`  argument of `getEulerYPR()` but I don't know if that will help.

Good luck.

---

Originally posted by [rbbg](https://answers.ros.org/users/26757/rbbg/) with karma: 1823 on 2016-11-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Venkat Ganesh](https://answers.ros.org/users/26837/venkat-ganesh/) on 2016-11-14**:
Hello, thanks for your suggestion. Unfortunately, I still don't see the correct angle.
In `tf_broadcaster_node`, I have the same input: Y,P,R = (90,0,-90). However, in `tf_listener_node`, I see (0, 90, 90). I don't think it's an equivalent rotation.